# Cleaning jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins

What is a good strategy for cleaning Jenkins workspace?  After getting started with Jenkins in a large team, available workspace space is shrinking, even through jobs/pipelines seems to do due diligence to clean after themselves.

The current approach I am trying: iterate through every node (including master),
under $WORKSPACE, find and delete directories over given age.  Does this seem safe?

I tried online groovy code snippets to run via Jenkins console, and those got rejected with errors.  I'd rather stick with simple code that is known to work.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have a stage for each run that cleans the work space:

```
node {
   try {
       stage('Clean Work Space') {
           cleanWs()
           sh 'pwd'
           sh 'ls'
       }
   }
}
```

I would also refer to: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ws-cleanup/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Discard Old Builds" option on the Jobs to limit the number of builds stored for every job. This will reduce the disk space usage.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [deleteDir()](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#deletedir-recursively-delete-the-current-directory-from-the-workspace) command to clean the work space.

Comment: As far as I know all our current jobs use Discard Old Builds, and some use clean workspaces.  Perhaps not all our jobs had used this in the past: I found hundreds of gigs on dirs dated over few months old using Unix "find".

Answer (score -1):

The best strategy to delete the Workspaces is to either go by Sprint numbers (if you are using agile) or by Date modified (to retain latest top 5).

I have created a script that has Groovy scripts for both of the strategies mentioned above.

Here is my detailed blog on strategies to delete Jenkins workspace for all jobs and individual jobs.

https://medium.com/@vishnuteja/jenkins-cleanup-workspace-reduce-disk-usage-18310097d3ef

**Here is the code for cleaning up workspaces by Date modified.**

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*

//manager.listener.logger.println new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a') + " / " + " -- Start Time" 

//Get value from String Parameter
MAX_BUILDS = manager.build.buildVariables.get("MAX_BUILDS").toInteger()

for (job in Jenkins.instance.items) 
{

    int count = 0

    manager.listener.logger.println "\n ***Job Name: "+job.name+"***"

        if(job.workspace!=null && job.workspace!="")  //Check if there is a workspace associated with the Job
        {
            manager.listener.logger.println "Workspace path : " + job.workspace

            String workspace = job.workspace

            File folder = new File(workspace)

            if(folder!=null && folder.exists()) //Check if the Workspace folder exists
            {
                // Get all files and folders within the Workspace of current job. 
                //Iterate through only folders and sort em by Modified Date.

                File[] files = new File(workspace).listFiles().sort(){
                a,b -> b.lastModified().compareTo a.lastModified()
                }
                .each{
                    if(!it.isFile()) //Check only for folders
                    {
                        if(count < MAX_BUILDS)
                            manager.listener.logger.println new Date(it.lastModified()).format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a') + " /" + it.name + " -- Save" 
                        else
                        {
                            manager.listener.logger.println new Date(it.lastModified()).format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a') + " /" + it.name + " ** Deleted" 
                            it.deleteDir()
                        }
                        count++
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                manager.listener.logger.println "Workspace is empty or doesn't exist"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            manager.listener.logger.println "No Workspace associated with this job"
        }
    }

}

//manager.listener.logger.println new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a') + " / " + " -- End Time"
```

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thank you. I have made the appropriate changes to my answer.